# How to merge branch to trunk automatically

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want merge branch to trunk using command, because file are too much. But there are no option to use accept-theirs-full. So I'm looking for the alternative way to merge automatically.

```
svn merge -r 1:Head --accept-theirs-full ^C:xxx/branch ^Cxxx/tags
```

Tortoise SVN version is 1.14.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in your question is wrong because it has invalid parameters.

First, you need to ensure that your branch is in sync with trunk. See [SVNBook | Keeping a branch in sync](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/basicmerging/#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync).

Then you need to reintegrate your branch into trunk as described in [SVNBook | Reintegrating a branch](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/basicmerging/#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate).

Steps for reintegrating a branch into trunk are as follows:

1. Check out your trunk and `cd` into this working copy (or switch your existing working copy to trunk).
2. Run the `svn merge ^/branches/mybranchname/` command. You need to replace the path to your branch with an actual path from your repository.
3. Examine the result of your merge and commit it if all is fine.

Note that all this can be done through TortoiseSVN's UI. The option is called "Merge a range of revisions" and can be usually done in a Next-Next-Finish manner. See [TortoiseSVN Manual | Merging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html).